# Select all non null fields

Tags: sql, hive

I'm new to SQL. I have table with four columns containing values.

Example:

```
Id, country, adresse, dt
C1, LA, null, 2022-09-10
Null, Null,Null, 2022-09-11
Null, Null, Null, 2022-09-12
C2, null, null, 2022-10-01
```

I want to take all rows where id, country and adresse are not null in the same row. It means, I want to take row1, row4.

Query:

```sql
Select * 
from tb1 
where Id is not null and country is not null and adresse is not null
```

```
C1, LA, null, 2022-09-10
C2, null, null, 2022-10-01
```

It seems that my query doesn't return a row when value of id or country or adresse is null, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Your query seems to do exactly what you want it to do. Please explain why this result is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As you explained in the description , you should be using `or` condition and not `and` condition.

```
select * from tb1 
    where Id is not null or country is not null or adresse is not null
```

Assuming that you want to filter the rows that does not have all three values as `null`.